# Data Frames Looping R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have 136 data frames with multiples lenghts and 2 variables each: `compl001` to `compl136`. I've been trying to loop between them with no luck so
 far. I'm actually trying to make comparisons inside each data frame. There is a value set as "Há" or "Não Há". The main porblem I'm facing is that when I use paste to look betweem data.frames it is understoo as a character not a previous data.frame on my environment.

It's something like that:

```
Min1     Min2
Há       Há
Não Há   Há
Não Há   Não Há
```

My goal is to pick compl1 pass trough all it's length and if `compl001$Min1 = compl001$Min2` then a agreement counter increases by 1./

```
concc = 0
discc = 0

for (i in 1:136){
        ##Chosing the Min1 and Min2 names (it changes between data.frames but here it reveals NULL because understand paste as character)
    assign('parsel' ,colnames<-(paste0("compl00", i))) 

    for (j in 1:length(paste0("compl00", i))){

      if ((assign("a",(paste0("compl00",i,'$',parsel[1],'[',j,']'))))==(assign('b',paste0("compl00",i,'$',parsel[2],'[',j+1,']'))))
      {concc = concc + 1}
     else
       {discc = discc + 1}
    }
}
```

Comment: If all the dataframes have the same two variables wouldn't it be easier to rbind them all together and then perform your analysis? I guess, size may be a concern here. Not sure on what your data looks like.

Comment: It would probably be easier to put all of your dataframes into a list and loop over the dataframes themselves

Answer (score 2):

So I created a list of dataframes to simulate your data based on what you've described.

```
dfs<-lapply(seq(1,136), 
        function(x) data.frame(Min1=sample(c("Ha", "Nao Ha"), replace = TRUE,size = 50), 
                                  Min2=sample(c("Ha", "Nao Ha"),replace = TRUE,size = 50)))
```

Then the results can be looped over using lapply and quickly tabulated with the `table()` To get just those in agreement we sum the 1,1 and 2,2 cells.

```
results<-lapply(dfs, function(x) {
                tmp<-table(x)
                sum(tmp[1,1], tmp[2,2])
                })
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's still kind of a mystery how it's working but it did. Thank you bro!